# Problema con el cambio entre ventanas C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms, c#-8.0

Me encuentro trabajando con un compañero en un proyecto y nos topamos con un problema en las ventanas, resulta que tenemos una ventana Maestra por así decirlo que es un menú y se encarga de mostrar dentro de ese mismo menú otras ventanas[image: Menú]

Cuando cambiamos de ventana todo funciona correcto, se remplaza el panel con el contenido y muestra otro Frame, eso se realiza con este código

```
 private void OpenChildForm(Form childForm, string vistaNombre)
    {
        //open only form
        if (currentChildForm != null)
        {
            currentChildForm.Close();
        }
        currentChildForm = childForm;
        //End
        childForm.TopLevel = false;
        childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        pnl_contenido.Controls.Add(childForm);
        pnl_contenido.Tag = childForm;
        childForm.BringToFront();
        childForm.Show();
        lbl_opcionActual.Text = vistaNombre;
    }
```

El problema viene cuando presionamos un botón que tenemos dentro de la ventana administrar evento

[image: Problema]

Nuestro principal problema es que necesitamos que la ventana del menú se esconda y que solo se vea la de editar evento, no encuentro una solución en este momento, puede que sea por llevar mucho tiempo programando pero me vi en la necesidad de solicitar ayuda, quizás sea un problema muy pequeño pero no vislumbro el problema, aquí el código que usamos para intentar de esconder la ventana, cabe mencionar que también probamos con this.hide(), pero como era de esperar solo esconde la ventana del panel.

```
        private void btn_end_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        VistaConcluirEvento vce = new VistaConcluirEvento();
        VistaMenu vm = new VistaMenu();
        vm.Hide();
        vce.Show();
    }
```

**Adjunto proyecto completo por si no se puede entender el código con los fragmentos que coloque, de antemano muchísimas gracias, cualquier consejo lo agradeceré, pido disculpa si mi lenguaje técnico aun es pobre.**

https://www.mediafire.com/file/m4terwh1q9ae9yz/EventCast.rar/file

Comment: ESto no hace nada: VistaMenu vm = new VistaMenu();
        vm.Hide() estas escondiendo una ventana que acabas de crear.. querias esconder una ventana ya creada? las ventanas son objetos ocmo cualquier otro.. si haces new, es un nuevo objeto, o una nueva ventana....

Comment: ademas.. esto es c#, no se que tiene que ver vb.net.. en este caso iba mejora aclarar si era winforms o wpf...

Comment: Creo que entiendo lo que me dices, pero como puedo traer la instancia ya creada con anterioridad?

Comment: Quizá, como el menú es un panel puedes variar el ancho a 0 de modo que el panel derecho se expanda hacia la izquierda por el dock. Otra alternativa es tener un frame oculto que cubra el lado izquierdo y derecho y lpones en este la ventana Administrar y lo haces visible en primer plano. Al salir restauras las otras

Comment: ES un objeto como cualquier otro. Como pasas instancias de un objeto de una clase a otra? de la misma forma, una vez que creas el formulario, podes pasar esa variable al nuevo formulario o a donde sea, de forma tal que tengas acceso... un formulario es una clase como cualquier otra!!!! la unica diferencia es que sabe dibujarse en pantalla....